# How to pass json objects in azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure logic app through which I am reading an XML file(Input) by parsing into json & getting all the XML tags(with corresponding values) as json objects.

Further i have to do some calculation through Azure function so how can I connect logic app(which is already created to read XML data) to Azure function & pass json objects(which i got in my Logic app by parsing the XML) within the Azure function(in C#).

Comment: have you gone through this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, we can [call Azure function inside Azure Logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions) or [call Azure logic app inside Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-scenario-function-sb-trigger). But please note that if you want to call Azure function inside Azure logic app, the function just can be HTTP trigger. For more details about how to call function inside logic app, please refer to the [blog](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2016/04/14/logic-apps-tips-and-tricks-to-use-azure-functions-inside-logic-apps/) and official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-twitter-email)